# How to get last edited items in editable TableView in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I encounter a problem with my TableView in JavaFX. The first state of my table view is that:

[image: first state of my table view]

Then when I edit my TableView values in "Nombre de places à réserver" column, the new values stay displayed in my TableView but when I try to get Items and display them in the console, I receive the old values of my TableView (It displays "0" instead of "8" on line 2 of the console):

[image: second state of my table view]

Here's my controller code for the window:

```
public class ReserverWindowController {

    private SpectacleDto spectacleToReserve;

    public TableView<SpectacleReservationDto> listeTarifs = new TableView<SpectacleReservationDto>();
    public ObservableList<SpectacleReservationDto> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public Label labelNomSpectacle;

    public Button reserverButton;

    public void setSpectacleToReserve(SpectacleDto leSpectacle){
        //On récupère le spectacle sélectionné
        this.spectacleToReserve = leSpectacle;

        //On assigne le texte au label
        labelNomSpectacle.setText(spectacleToReserve.getNom());

        for (TarifDto unTarif:spectacleToReserve.getTarifs()) {
            data.add(new SpectacleReservationDto(unTarif.getName(), unTarif.getPrice(), 0));
        }

        TableColumn nomTarifColumn = new TableColumn("Tarifs");
        nomTarifColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SpectacleReservationDto, String>("tarifName"));

        TableColumn prixTarifColumn = new TableColumn("Prix");
        prixTarifColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SpectacleReservationDto, String>("tarifPrice"));

        TableColumn nbPlacesReserveColumn = new TableColumn("Nombre de places à réserver");
        nbPlacesReserveColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SpectacleReservationDto, String>("nbPlacesReserve"));
        nbPlacesReserveColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new NumberStringConverter()));

        listeTarifs.setItems(data);
        listeTarifs.setEditable(true);
        listeTarifs.getColumns().addAll(nomTarifColumn, prixTarifColumn, nbPlacesReserveColumn);
        listeTarifs.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
    }

    public void reserverSpectacle() {
        System.out.println("test réserver");
    }

    public void rafraichirPrixTotal(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {

            ObservableList<SpectacleReservationDto> lesReservations = listeTarifs.getItems();

            for (SpectacleReservationDto uneReservation:lesReservations) {
                System.out.println("Prix: " + uneReservation.getTarifPrice());
                System.out.println("Nombre de places à réserver: " + uneReservation.getNbPlacesReserve());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is SpectacleReservationDto class:

```
public class SpectacleReservationDto {
    private String tarifName;
    private float tarifPrice;
    private int nbPlacesReserve;

    public SpectacleReservationDto(String tarifName, float tarifPrice, int nbPlacesReserve) {
        this.tarifName = tarifName;
        this.tarifPrice = tarifPrice;
        this.nbPlacesReserve = nbPlacesReserve;
    }

    public String getTarifName() {
        return tarifName;
    }

    public void setTarifName(String tarifName) {
        this.tarifName = tarifName;
    }

    public int getNbPlacesReserve() {
        return nbPlacesReserve;
    }

    public void setNbPlacesReserve(int nbPlacesReserve) {
        this.nbPlacesReserve = nbPlacesReserve;
    }

    public float getTarifPrice() {
        return tarifPrice;
    }

    public void setTarifPrice(float tarifPrice) {
        this.tarifPrice = tarifPrice;
    }
}
```

The `rafraichirPrixTotal` function is called when I edit values in my TableView.
So how can I get the last edited values ?

Comment: Thank you it's included in the question

Comment: column has wrong type - should be Integer, not String. Plus, best to expose the data as Properties, not only via getters/setters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In only getter and setter are available, `PropertyValueFactory` creates a property that does not write to the item. To fix this you could

1. Use a property and fix the type of the column/use a converter:

   ```
   TableColumn<SpectacleReservationDto, Number> nbPlacesReserveColumn = new TableColumn("Nombre de places à réserver");
   nbPlacesReserveColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SpectacleReservationDto, Number>("nbPlacesReserve"));
   nbPlacesReserveColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new NumberStringConverter(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance())));
   ```

   ```
   private final IntegerProperty nbPlacesReserve = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

   public IntegerProperty nbPlacesReserveProperty() {
       retrun nbPlacesReserve;
   }

   public int getNbPlacesReserve() {
       return nbPlacesReserve.get();
   }

   public void setNbPlacesReserve(int value) {
       nbPlacesReserve.set(value);
   }
   ```
2. Alternatively set the `onEditCommit` handler for the column:

   ```
   TableColumn<SpectacleReservationDto, Number> nbPlacesReserveColumn = new TableColumn("Nombre de places à réserver");
   nbPlacesReserveColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SpectacleReservationDto, Number>("nbPlacesReserve"));
   nbPlacesReserveColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new NumberStringConverter(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance())));
   nbPlacesReserveColumn.setOnEditCommit(evt -> evt.getRowValue().setNbPlacesReserve(evt.getNewValue()));
   ```